# ABS/ stabilisation control error

Tags: vw, suspension, sensor, polo

I have polo 1.2Tsi 2015 model, here is the problem : my clutch  eas dead and i bought new one and fitted it in, after i started the car  it did not move at all, it showed ABS/ STABILISATION CONTROL ERROR(ESC)  on the screen and it seems like all wheels are locked. Help me please.

Comment: Have you double-checked all the cables that you connected/disconnected? There may be something plugged in wrongly or not plugged in at all.